# Why won't visual studio code appear in the list of programs in control panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code, control-panel

When I install programs like photoshop, it appear in the programs list in control panel but why not for visual studio code?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code should be found under the name of "Code", like this:

[image]